# Translation animation not showing when weight of view is set to zero afterwards

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to animate the showing/hiding of a menu in my app. When I use the showMenu function, the animation works fine. However, when I use the hideMenu function the animation does not play and the menu remains visible.

Without the animation included, hideMenu works fine. The menu_hide animation works fine if used in the showMenu function; the showMenu animation does not work when put in the hideMenu function.

I assume that the animation is not playing because the weight of the view in question is being set to zero immediately after the animation is set. How do I get around this?

```
private void showMenu() {
    animate(tableLayout, R.anim.menu_show);
    setWeights(3, 7, 10);
    ShowMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void hideMenu() {
    animate(tableLayout, R.anim.menu_hide);
    setWeights(3, 17, 0);
    ShowMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 

private void setWeights(int i, int j, int k) {
    int titlePadding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_pad);
    LayoutParams titleParams = new LayoutParams(matchParent, 0, i);
    titleParams.setMargins(titlePadding, 0, titlePadding, 0);
    titleLayout.setLayoutParams(titleParams);
    listLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(matchParent, 0, j));
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(matchParent, 0, k));
}

public void animate(View view, int animationId) {
        view.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, animationId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems and seems view which has 0 weight is ignored. Try 0.001f instead of 0f.